# How do I make Javascript's date interpret it correctly?

Tags: javascript

Javascript's date are supposed to be in the month/day/year order but this:

```js
new Date('6/6/2020') // Interpreted in the day/month/year order, 6/6/2020 when it should've interpreted in the month/day/year order 6/6/2020
```

is interpreted as if it's in the day/month/year order?
How do I make it so it'll interpret it correctly?
I've tried

```js
new Date('11/11/2020')
```

but the bug still presist

Comment: _"when it should've interpreted in the month/day/year"_ - Why? JavaScript is not only available for the US (and some other countries that use M/D/Y).

Comment: hard to tell what you are asking. '6/6/2020' is the same string whether its day/month or month/day

Comment: Are you asking how you can parse `'6/6/2020'` in month/day/year order, or are you asking which format you should use instead?

Comment: What “bug” are you talking about? Why do you only give us examples where the order doesn’t matter? There are millions of _date format_ questions. What have you researched and tried and how exactly did your attempts not work?

Comment: @Rick it's a great example of why a date string doesn't look like that :-)

Comment: Do you have examples where you think it's interpreting day/month/year instead of month/day/year and the day/month are not the same, or did you just get confused by the cases where month/day match?

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass a string to `Date()`. You're asking for trouble if you do.

It is ***strongly discouraged***. From the MDN web docs:

> **Note:** Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse()`, which works the same way) is *strongly discouraged* due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

Just because you manage to get it working on your browser, there's no guarantee it will work on a different browser.

If you want to set a particular date, use this form:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex, day);
```

where `year, monthIndex, day` are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Date's constructor takes an argument like that. Here's what the doc says → https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

It could be either a day string, e.g. Wed Jul 28 1993, or a timestamp or integer year, month, day values as a list of arguments.